# HighChart - Custom Paths Not Linked to Chart

Tags: highcharts

I have a HighStock chart that is pulling in some OHLC data and creating a chart with 3 series - 1 candlestick, 1 volume, and 1 set of flags. This all works fine.

I want to add some custom trend lines to the chart. I will determine the points and do the paths based on custom logic.

The problem is that when I use the `Renderer` from the Chart to draw my path, the path is not connected to the underlying chart. As the chart date range is modified and/or new points are added to the primary `series`, the placement and size of my custom path remains unchanged. It is constant.

I need the location/endpoints of the custom path to be tied to the datapoints of the chart, not the coordinates of the svg drawing. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Here is the portion of the code that is adding a simple path from `pointa` to `pointb`. The path renders as expected but is then static:

```
    buildPath: function(pointa, pointb){
        this.myChart.renderer.path(this.buildPathArray(pointa,pointb))
            .attr({
                'stroke-width': 2,
                stroke: 'red'
            }).add();
    },
    buildPathArray: function(pointa, pointb){
        var pathArray = [];
        pathArray.push('M');
        pathArray.push(pointa.plotX);
        pathArray.push(pointa.plotClose);
        pathArray.push('L');
        pathArray.push(pointb.plotX);
        pathArray.push(pointb.plotClose);
        pathArray.push('Z');
        return pathArray;
    }
```

Per request, I created [a JS Fiddle that demonstrates the general issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/M8yd7/72/)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's not very clear, can you jsfiddle it ?

Comment: I updated the original Q with a jsfiddle link. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

This doesn't seem to come for free with Highcharts. Or if it does I did not find out the technique.

I had to use both the `load` and `redraw` events of the `chart` object contained in my `StockChart`.

On `load`, I draw the initial paths, aligned with the `Point` objects involved in my trending lines. As I build these `path` objects (`SVGElement` objects containing the genuine SVG `path` elements) I keep track of them in an array.

On `redraw`, I have to both destroy the old trend lines and create new ones. So I loop over my array of old elements and remove each from their own `parentNode`. Then I draw a fresh version of my trend lines based on the newly plotted location of each of my relevant `Point` objects.

The end result is that on each `redraw` event, the lines appear to move with the chart, when they're really being destroyed and recreated.